# Convert ag grid table to PDF file

Tags: angular, ag-grid, jspdf

I want to convert ag-grid table to pdf file. So I use "jspdf" library.I exported the ag-grid table to pdf. But I lost the styles of pdf file. I exported the pdf without table structure and any styles. So how can I resolve that issue?

This is my code for .html file

```
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right"  (click)="downloadAsPDF()" >
              Export PDF
         </button>
        </div>    
         <div class="col-sm-12" id="pdfTable" #pdfTable>
            <ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 500px; row-gap: 30px;" rowStyle="height:50px;"
            class="ag-theme-balham" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [enableSorting]="true"
            [animateRows]="true" rowSelection="multiple" [floatingFilter]="true" [enableColResize]="true"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions" rowHeight="25">
            </ag-grid-angular>
         </div>
```

This the code for .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF  from 'jspdf'; 
@Component({ 
 selector: 'app-classroom',
 templateUrl: './classroom.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./classroom.component.scss'],

 })
 export class ClassroomComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild('pdfTable') pdfTable: { nativeElement: any; }; 
renderer: any;
element: any;

classrooms: Classroom[];
classroom = true;
selectedClassroom: Classroom;
private gridApi;
subscription: Subscription;
frameworkComponents: any;
rowData: Array<any> = [];
columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'Classroom Name', field: 'classroomName', width:200, filter: "agTextColumnFilter", 
  filterParams: { defaultOption: "startsWith" }}, 
  { headerName: 'Create Time', field: 'createdTime', width:200, filter: "agTextColumnFilter", 
  filterParams: { defaultOption: "startsWith" }}, ]

gridOptions = {
 };

constructor(private classroomService: ClassroomsService,private http: HttpClient, private 
 alertService: AlertService ) { }
 ngOnInit() {

downloadAsPDF() {
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  const specialElementHandlers = {
  '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
   return true;
   }};
   const pdfTable = this.pdfTable.nativeElement;
   doc.fromHTML(pdfTable.innerHTML, 9, 20, {
   width: 190,
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
   });
   doc.save('classroom report.pdf');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`pdfMake` is an excellent library to export ag-Grid with.

The ag-Grid API allows you to iterate over all header rows and data rows to generate a docDefinition that will be exported as a PDF table.

The method can generate the columns to export:

```
function getColumnsToExport() {
let columnsToExport = [];

columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns().forEach(col => {
  let pdfExportOptions = getPdfExportOptions(col.getColId());
  if (pdfExportOptions && pdfExportOptions.skipColumn) {
    return;
  }
  let headerCell = createHeaderCell(col);
  columnsToExport.push(headerCell);
});

return columnsToExport;
}
```

and the rows to export:

```
function getRowsToExport(columnsToExport) {
let rowsToExport = [];

gridApi.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort(node => {
  let rowToExport = columnsToExport.map(({ colId }) => {
    let cellValue = gridApi.getValue(colId, node);
    let tableCell = createTableCell(cellValue, colId);
    return tableCell;
  });
  rowsToExport.push(rowToExport);
});

return rowsToExport;
}
```

See the example below for more:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ag-grid-pdf-make?file=pdfExport%2FdocDefinition.js

Answer (score 0):

I think jsPDf will not support images and CSS styles, But i have a work around

[example link](https://jsfiddle.net/pgbL1zhj/)

I tried this with `jsPDF` and `dom-to-image` libraries

Comment: I tried this code. As I previously said I want to pdf ag-grid table. So I got some errors.

Comment: Error while reading CSS rules from https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500 SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: Error while reading CSS rules from https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: So can you explain that issue?

Answer (score 0):

By using the csv export the export will be significantly simpler and return the rendered values.

```
const csvData = gridApi.getDataAsCsv();
  if (csvData) {
    const csvRows = csvData.split('\n');
    const rowsToExport = [];
    csvRows.forEach((row, index) => {
      const rowToExport = row
        .substring(0, row.lastIndexOf(',')) /* remove return */
        .split(',')
        .map((cell) => {
          return {
            text: cell.replaceAll('"', ''),
            style: {
              fillColor:
                index === 0 ? '#CCCCCC' : undefined /* header row background */
            },
          };
        });
      rowsToExport.push(rowToExport);
    });
    return rowsToExport;
  }

pdfMake
    .createPdf({
      pageOrientation: 'landscape',
      content: [
        {
          table: {
            headerRows: 1,
            widths: 'auto',
            body: rows,
          },
        },
      ],
    })
    .download("your-file-name");
```